# Processing batch file with variables spanning multiple lines

Tags: batch-file, dos

There are quite a few posts discussing split lines in batch files, but I can't quite get things working for my requirement. I want to have a properties file containing sets of IP lists and then process those lists in a batch file. So a properties file something like this (I don't want the lists on one line as there may be quite a few and a single line would make it difficult to read):

```
IPLIST_1=^
12.34.56.1 ^
21.43.65.2 ^
5.8.001.3

IPLIST_2=^
222.11.33.1 ^
10.1.1.2
```

and a batch file that does something like this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /f "delims=" %%x in (iplists.txt) DO (set "%%x")
FOR %%A IN (%IPLIST_1%) DO (
some stuff
)
```

but it's not working as I'd hoped. If I have a batch file like this everything is ok:

```
FOR %%A IN (^
12.34.56.1 ^
21.43.65.2 ^
5.8.001.3) DO (
some stuff
)
```

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: do you mean `SET IPLIST_1=...`? (There is no `set` in your examples, is this a typo in question, or your real code? (in the latter case it shouldn't work))

Comment: Hi Anton. The first FOR loop sets IPLIST_1 and IPLIST_2, the second FOR loop is then meant to go through the IPs in IPLIST_1. That's the intention anyway.

Comment: I mean, there's a command __SET__ for setting variables. `SET NAME=VALUE` is okay, but `NAME=VALUE` without set is an error. Do you have the `SET` keyword in your real code?

Comment: No I do not have a SET. The first for loop in the batch file reads the properties and it does the SET - i.e the line `FOR /f "delims=" %%x in (iplists.txt) DO (SET "%%x")` is what does the SET.

Comment: `FOR %%A IN (iplists.txt) do (some stuff)` ?

Comment: Would be any problem if your properties file may have a `set ` word before each IPLIST? Something like this: `SET IPLIST_1=^` `12.34.56.1 ^` ... You need to also rename the file from iplists.txt to iplists.bat. This way, you just `call iplists.bat` to define all your IPLISTS in the way you want. Topic title say "processing batch file", but it really is "processing TEXT file"...

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set "LIST="
for /f "tokens=1 delims=^^" %%I in (iplists.txt) do (

  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  echo %%I | find "IPLIST_" &&  for %%P in (!LIST!) do ( something with %%P ) & (  set "IPLIST_=")
  echo %%I | find "IPLIST_" || ( set "LIST=!LIST! %%I")
  endlocal

)
```

It was hard to understand what you have here.My assumption:

1. You have file iplists.txt
2. You want the bat to interpreter each list as a whole line but , the IPs are on separate lines , so you tried to unite them with **^**  (this is fultile in fact)
3. you want to process each list in a FOR loop

The code above is my offer - In outer loop the **^** are escaped - you don't need them at all but they will not hurt.You cannot unite the list in one line as in a batch script.

---

With first for I'm starting to read the list.txt line by line.I have an empty list initially  passed to inner FOR - but iterates items separated with space , and if there are no such it will do nothing.  The **setlocal enabledelayedexpansion** is to make changes in LIST visible inside brackets . with the two `echo %%I | find "IPLIST_"` I'm performing conditional execution. If the line %%I not contains `IPLIST_` string the second line will be executed and the LIST will be expanded with the next IP. If it contains "IPLIST_" will be executed the first line where the list will be processed by inner FOR and in the end deleted.And then we start again till the end of file.